# jQuery dynamic input value of another Input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three items that I am attempting to get on the page.  First two not a problem.  The third is dependent on the what is selected in the second select option if more details are needed.  The third option hides or shows based on second.  So no problem there.  The code is here:

```
// Create a Javascript class to handle the form.
function InquiryCardForm() {
    var objSelf = this;

    // Get a jQuery reference to the form.
    this.Form = $( "#inqueryCard-form" );

    // Get jQuery references to the key fields in our contact
    // form. This way, we don't have to keep looking them up.
    // This will make it faster.
    this.DOMReferences = {
        // Form elements
        ID: this.Form.find( "input[ name = 'id' ]" ),
        SourceCode: this.Form.find( "input[ name = 'sourceCode' ]" ),
        SourceValue: this.Form.find( "select[ name = 'source' ]" ),
        SourceText: this.Form.find( "input[ name = 'other"
            +this.Form.find( "input[ name = 'sourceCode' ]" ).val()
            +this.Form.find( "select[ name = 'source' ]").val() +"' ]" )
    };
```

So I have HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="inqueryCard" id="inqueryCard-form">
...
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="sourceCode" value="SRCE">
            <select id="source" name="source">
                <option value="" selected>*** Select ***</option>
                <option value="1" data-more="N">Web Search</option>
                <option value="2" data-more="N">Word Of Mouth</option>
                <option value="3" data-more="O">Other</option>
                <option value="4" data-more="R">Other</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="otherDIV_SRCE1">
                <p> <input type="text" name="otherSRCE1" value="" /></p>
            </div>
            <div id="otherDIV_SRCE2">
                <p> <input type="text" name="otherSRCE2" value="" /></p>
            </div>
            <div id="otherDIV_SRCE3">
                <p>Please Specify <input type="text" name="otherSRCE3" value="" /></p>
            </div>
            <div id="otherDIV_SRCE4">
                <p>Must Share <input type="text" name="otherSRCE4" value="" /></p>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Issue here is that the SourceText object is not an object.  I am hiding or showing the div based on the selection of "source".

Please note that I was able to get this working on the Submit Form function like this

```
var code = objSelf.DOMReferences.SourceCode.val();
var value = objSelf.DOMReferences.SourceValue.val();
var SourceText = objSelf.Form.find( "input[ name = 'other" + code + value + "' ]" );
```

But I wanted to do this in the this.DOMReferences.   Due to me having about 21 other items on this page that will work very similar to this.

Thank you in advance.  (first time posting anything, so let me know if I forgot something that should be here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please update you function:

```
function InquiryCardForm() 
{
    var objSelf = this;

    this.Form = $( "#inqueryCard-form" );

    var select = this.Form.find( "select[ name = 'source' ]" );

    this.DOMReferences = 
    {
        // Form elements
        ID: this.Form.find( "input[ name = 'id' ]" ),
        SourceCode: this.Form.find( "input[ name = 'sourceCode' ]" ),
        SourceValue: select ,
        SourceText: function()
        {
            var index = select.find(":selected").val();
            return this.Form.find( "input[ name = 'other" + SourceCode.val() + index + "' ]" );
        }
    };
}
```